# Compose key sequences result in the wrong character

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to type the letters "Ć" and "ć" using the compose key sequences, however, they don't seem to work:

- <kbd>Compose</kbd>,<kbd>,</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> results in a "ç", which is fine
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>,<kbd>,</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> results in a "Ç", which is also fine
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>,<kbd>'</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> (that is, with a small "c") results in a "ç", which is *not* good, it shouldn't
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>,<kbd>'</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does nothing, which is not good either, it shuold be a "Ć"

Here's the result of `grep "LATIN .* LETTER C WITH CEDILLA$" /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`:

```
<dead_cedilla> <C>                      : "Ç"   Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <comma> <C>                 : "Ç"   Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <C> <comma>                 : "Ç"   Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <cedilla> <C>               : "Ç"   Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_cedilla> <c>                      : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <comma> <c>                 : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <c> <comma>                 : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <cedilla> <c>               : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

And here's the result of `grep "LATIN .* LETTER C WITH ACUTE$" /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`:

```
<dead_acute> <C>                        : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <acute> <C>                 : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <C>            : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <C> <apostrophe>            : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<dead_acute> <c>                        : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <acute> <c>                 : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <c>            : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <c> <apostrophe>            : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
```

This is my keyboard layout:

```
setxkbmap -layout us \
    -variant dvp \
    -option compose:ralt \
    -option keypad:atm \
    -option numpad:shift3 \
    -option altwin:meta_win \
    -option kpdl:semi
```

And this is the contents of my `.Xmodmap`:

```
clear Lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

How do I fix the mappings so that I can type ć and Ć using the right sequence?

Comment: I can't help you with your question but you might get more responses on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Please follow the guidelines outlined in [this Meta Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/259532) if you are planning to cross-post/move your question.

Comment: Are you actually using the `en_US.UTF-8` locale? Also, are you witnessing the same behaviour in GTK+ applications as in non-GTK+ applications (*e.g.* urxvt)?

Comment: @SamHocevar I'm not sure, good question. My `/etc/locale.conf` contains `LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"` and `LC_COLLATE="C"`. I use the UK English locale with a custom dvp layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely caused by GTK+, namely [bug 705168](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705168). GTK+ overrides the X11 compose rules so whatever you may have in `/usr/share/X11/locale` will be ignored by default.

You can patiently wait for the bug to be fixed, but I would suggest switching to the X input method instead. This will ensure that GTK+ applications use the same input method as all other applications and properly parse your locale’s `Compose` rules. It is as simple as adding the line `export GTK_IM_MODULE='xim'` in your `~/.xprofile` file.

Comment: Thanks @SamHocevar. I've started another bounty so that I can award you, but you'll have to wait the minimum one day before I can award it.